# Find the smallest number $n$ such that there exist polynomials $f_{1}, f_{2},...,f_{n}$ with rational coeﬃcients

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Find the smallest number $n$ such that there exist polynomials $f_{1}, f_{2},...,f_{n}$ with rational coeﬃcients satisfying $$x^{2}+7=f_{1}(x)^{2}+f_{2}(x)^{2}+...+f_{n}(x)^{2}.$$

**It's Olympiad question.**

My try is.. The equality $x^{2}+7=x^{2}+2^{2}+1^{2}+1^{2}+1^{2}$,  shows that $n\leq 5$ It remains to show that $x^{2}+7$ is not a sum of four (or less) squares of polynomials with rational coeﬃcients.

is there any one can show me a full solution?

Comment: Well you're on the right track in that you only have to figure out the smallest way to write $7$ as a sum of squares.  The hitch is you have to deal with it over $\Bbb Q$ and not just $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @GregoryGrant ok, but I should write a full solution, and I don't know how

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/582188/is-an-integer-a-sum-of-two-rational-squares-iff-it-is-a-sum-of-two-integer-squar and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_three-square_theorem

Comment: @Padrt There are quite a few different solutions here: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h418641p2362006

Comment: You should be able to mix these two to prove you need at least four integers to make their squares add $7$

Comment: after that you should prove having more than one polynomial of the form $(ax-b)^2$ won't help.

Comment: @dREaM Does that hold also for rational coefficients?

Comment: he would have to use the idea from the first link to extend to rational coefficients