# Is it an open problem? (Sums of squares)

Tags: rational-numbers, sums-of-squares, open-problem

Has it been proven that if n can be represented as a sum of squares of two rational numbers, then it can also be represented as a sum of squares of two integers?

This is a relatively simple statement, but I haven't found a simple proof for it, at least not yet. If it has been proven/is known to be true, does it require very advanced mathematics to prove it?

Comment: This? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/582188/is-an-integer-a-sum-of-two-rational-squares-iff-it-is-a-sum-of-two-integer-squar

Comment: oh thanks! you're right :)

Comment: the same thing for three squares is in Serre's little book.