# For a number field $K$, is an integer a sum of two $K$'s elements squares iff it is a sum of two integer squares?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, sums-of-squares

Sorry for my bad English.

There is a famous problem of elementally number theory as follow;

[Is an integer a sum of two rational squares iff it is a sum of two integer squares?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/582188/is-an-integer-a-sum-of-two-rational-squares-iff-it-is-a-sum-of-two-integer-squar)

Now I want know about this generalization for a number field.

i.e. is the next Prop. true?

> Let $K$ be any algebraic number field ,and $\mathscr{O}_K$  be ring of integers  of $K$.
> For any $a\in \mathscr{O}_K$, $a$ can be written as $r^2+s^2$ for some $r,s\in K$ iff can be written as $b^2+c^2$ for some $b,c\in \mathscr{O}_K$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not true. For example, let $K=\Bbb{Q}(i)$ with
$\mathcal{O}_K=\Bbb Z[i]$. Then
$$
i = \left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)^2.
$$
This shows $i$ is a sum of two squares in $\Bbb {Q}(i)$.

However, it is impossible to write $i$ as a finite sum of squares in ${\Bbb Z}[i]$ since
$$
(a+bi)^2 = a^2 - b^2 + 2abi
$$
has even imaginary part when $a$ and $b$ are in $\Bbb {Z}$.  Thus any finite sum of squares in $\Bbb {Z}[i]$ has even imaginary part, so such a sum can't be equal to $i$.