# What number field is sum of two squares theorem true？

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, sums-of-squares

Sorry for my bad English.

There is
[sum of two squares theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem) 
. It can’t be generalized for some  number field, for example $\mathbb{Q}(i)$
[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4468826/for-a-number-field-k-is-an-integer-a-sum-of-two-ks-elements-squares-iff-it).

Now I want to know useful criterions for number fields concerned about  when is this theorem true.

Comment: [This paper](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/ADCFormsI.pdf) seems relevant.