# Circles with rational points

Tags: elementary-number-theory, complex-numbers, circles

Let $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x^2+y^2 \in \mathbb{Q}$.
Do there exist $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $a^2 + b^2 = x^2 + y^2$?

Interpreted geometrically:
Consider the circle in $\mathbb{C}$ with center $0$ and radius $r := |x+iy|$.
Does it contain a rational point, i.e. do there exist $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $a+ib$ lies on that circle?

My first step to approach this was the following:
There exist coprime $p, q \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $r^2 = p/q$.
I think, that we can assume that $p$ and $q$ are both square-free.
For if $p=k^2p_0$ for some $k, p_0$, then we maybe can replace $r$ with $r/k$ and $p$ with $p_0$. If this works, then it works similarly for $q$.

But then I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: The [sum of two squares theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem) gives an immediate answer to this question.

Comment: $x,y$ are irrelevant. The only hypothesis is $r^2\in\Bbb Q.$ Or wlog: $r^2\in\Bbb N.$ Then, [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/582188).